# What is a 'cofiber sequence' in a triangulated category?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, definition, homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories

I am reading the definition of a localizing subcategory $\mathcal{D}$ of a triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$ (Definition 1.1.1 of the book [Axiomatic Stable Homotopy Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-128-610#:%7E:text=It%20starts%20with%20axioms%20defining,representability%2C%20to%20name%20a%20few.)). It refers to a 'cofiber sequence' $$X\to Y\to Z\to\Sigma X$$ in $\mathcal{C}$. **Does this mean the same as an exact/distinguished triangle or something else?** I can't think what else it could mean given the context but I'm not familiar with it being called a 'cofiber sequence'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these are exact/distinguished triangles. The terminology comes from stable homotopy theory. The stable homotopy category has the structure of a triangulated category, where the exact triangles are given by (co)fiber sequences of spectra.

Comment: In particular, see the first sentence in Definition A.1.1 in the document cited in the question.